# WinForm : Make control unfocusable

Tags: winforms, controls

My winform contains a TextBox that is the main control of the form. When I do CtrL + C, and often end up with an empty clipboard because for some reason the ActiveControl of the form is set to another control, like for instance the TabControl, the SplitContainer, etc. I tried to set those control TabStop = fasle, but to avail. Is there a way to prevent all controls from getting focus ? Not only regarding the mouse clicks, but also the tab keys.

Comment: thinking about this, I dont think this is possible to prevent the controls from becoming the activeControl. In order to drag the splitContainer splitter, it has to become the activeControl. Maybe the correct approach to accomplish what I want would be to reset the activeControl when the mouse release the splitter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can imagine trying with some native windows messages like `WM_SetFocus`, or some native windows styles like `WS_TABSTOP`, or some control styles like `ControlStyles.Selectable`, or `ControlStyles.UserMouse`, but I'd say you cannot find a generic solution which handles all controls.

What I'm proposing here (according to your comments, looking for a better way of handling focus rather than trying to make things focusable, which makes more sense in UX point of view as well) is handling TabControl and SplitterContainer focus related events:

- Tab control: Handle [SelectedIndexChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selectedindexchanged?view=windowsdesktop-7.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235), and then move the focus to the first focusable control of the tab.
- Splitter container: Handle [MouseDown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.mousedown?view=windowsdesktop-7.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) to trap the start of splitting, then store the active panel; later handle [SplitterMoved](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.splitter.splittermoved?view=windowsdesktop-7.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) and move the focus to he first focusable control of the active panel.

Here is what worked for me:

```
SplitterPanel activePanel;
private void splitContainer1_SplitterMoved(object sender, SplitterEventArgs e)
{
    splitContainer1.SelectNextControl(activePanel, 
        forward: true, tabStopOnly: true, nested: true, wrap: true);
}
private void splitContainer1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    activePanel = splitContainer1.Panel1.ContainsFocus ? splitContainer1.Panel1 :
        splitContainer1.Panel2.ContainsFocus ? splitContainer1.Panel2 : null;
}

private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var page = this.tabControl1.SelectedTab;
    page.SelectNextControl(null,
        forward: true, tabStopOnly: true, nested: true, wrap: true);

}
```

Comment: I think I cannot use "SelectNextControl" because I cannot be sure the control to give back the focus should be present in the current tabPage. What I wish is to give back the focus to whatever textbox that had the focus prior to the tab-change event or the split-move event, provided the control is still visible, of course. That bothers me because It seems that I would have to keep track of the last-focused-control , at an aplication-wide level.

Comment: Well, I imagine when a user switches the tab, they want to focus on a control in that tab. of when they drag a splitter of splitter container, they usually want to move the focus back to a control in splitter container. It's a little annoying to track the focus, but at least you can limit it to the container controls.

Comment: I wish the controls like SplitterContainer or TabControl had a setting to not accept the focus; but the thing is for many accessibility reasons, they need to keep the focus.

Comment: "I imagine when a user switches the tab, they want to focus on a control in that tab" that's close enough to being true, so I believe I will be alright

Answer (score 1):

Instead of preventing focus, which might cause problems for those trying to navigate your app using only the keyboard, implement the `IMessageFilter` interface and trap Ctrl-C for your whole app. Then you can simply put the contents of your "main textbox" on the clipboard manually:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form, IMessageFilter
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
    }

    bool IMessageFilter.PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x0100 && 
            (Keys)m.WParam.ToInt32() == Keys.C &&
            ModifierKeys == Keys.Control)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ctrl-C Trapped!");
            if (textBox1.SelectionLength > 0)
            {
                Clipboard.SetText(textBox1.SelectedText);
            }
            else
            {
                Clipboard.SetText(textBox1.Text);
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: also an interesting avenue. I will consider both,  thank you !